# Array só carrega último registro em PHP com PDO

Tags: php, json, array, pdo

Estou gerando as informações, porem só preenche a ultima linha da query executada dentro do Array, mesmo tendo a certeza que está rodando todas as linhas no foreach. Alguem tem ideia como preencher todos os arrays com todas as informações?

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

require_once('conexao.php');
$conexao = conexao();
$id_igreja = 1;

try{
$igreja = "1";
$sql = "SELECT descricao, data, hora FROM reuniao WHERE id_igreja = :igreja order by 2,3 LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':igreja', $id_igreja);
$stmt->execute();
$dados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  foreach ($dados as $consulta){
    $arr = [
    'descricao' => $consulta->descricao,
    'periodo' => $consulta->data,
    'hora' => $consulta->hora
    ];
}
$json = json_encode($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$fp = fopen("reuniao.json", "a");
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
echo $json;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERRO: ' . $e->getMessage() ;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está sempre substituindo o valor do array. Por isso que só preenche a última linha. O certo é adicionar os valores que são resgatados no banco, assim:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($dados as $consulta){
    // adiciona mais um registro no array $arr
    $arr[] = [
    'descricao' => $consulta->descricao,
    'periodo' => $consulta->data,
    'hora' => $consulta->hora
    ];
}
```

Se bem que talvez seja desnecessário, visto que o `fetchAll` já retorna um array. Logo, você poderia transformá-lo em `json` diretamente:

```
$dados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$json = json_encode($dados ,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```